# Use spacy docker API

Tags: python, curl, docker, request, spacy

I'm trying to use spacy as an API following as is shown [here](https://github.com/jgontrum/spacy-api-docker):

After installation the test case works just fine:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/api --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "This is a text that I want to be analyzed."}' -X POST
```

But I want to process the output with python, so I'm trying to use the requests library:

```
import requests
url     = "http://localhost:5000/api"
payload = {"text" : "This is a text that I want to be analyzed" }
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"} 
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
res.json()
```

But I'm getting an output error:

```
{u'message': u'The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'}
```

I tried also using the suggestion of this [tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/):

```
import requests

data = '{"text": "This is a text that I want to be analyzed."}'

requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api', data=data)
```

But isn't working either.

Comment: Can you add the command you are using to start the docker container as well as the logs of the respective container?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use This docker image

```
docker pull pasupulaphani/spacy-nlp
```

Start server

```
docker run --publish 4242:4242 -it spacy-nlp-zeromq:en
```

(OR) Start manually

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/zeromq --publish 4242:4242 --entrypoint=/bin/bash  -it spacy-nlp-zeromq:en
python3 /usr/zeromq/zeromq/server.py
```

API
parse

```
$ zerorpc  tcp://0.0.0.0:4242 parse "hotel new york"
```

u'[{"tag": "NN", "text": "hotel new york"}]'
entities

```
$ zerorpc  tcp://0.0.0.0:4242 entities "hotels in london"
```

u'[{"end": 6, "start": 0, "text": "hotels", "type": ""}, {"end": 16, "start": 10, "text": "london", "type": ""}]'
nounChunks

```
$ zerorpc  tcp://0.0.0.0:4242 nounChunks "hotels in london"
```

u'[{"text": "hotels"}, {"text": "london"}]'
Troubleshoot
Check if port is open

if ! nc -z 0.0.0.0 4242 2>&1 >/dev/null; then echo "NOT AVAILABLE"; fi